# SparkJava variable number of parameters

Tags: java, spark-java

Is there a way to have a variable number of parameters in a SparkJava route (i.e. a route that works with /:var1/:var2/:var3 as well as /:var1/:var2/:var3/:par4 and so on)?

Comment: ...the doc doesnt let assume so ... , but ["Routes.Path Groups"](http://sparkjava.com/documentation#path-groups) seem suitable for your need (!?)

Answer (score 2):

No.

But instead, you can use a variable number of **query**Params, since these are defined dynamically only when calling the route. Example:

If you wanted to support routes:

- `/someRoute/:var1/:var2/:var3`
- `/someRoute/:var1/:var2/:var3/:par4`,

replace them with only `/someRoute`, and in its handler use `request.queryMap()` to get a mapping of [queryMap <---> its value].

Then, when you call this route you can call it with a variable number of queryParams:

- `/someRoute?var1=abc&var2=def&var3=ghi`
- `/someRoute?var1=abc&var2=def&var3=ghi&var4=jkl`

The result of `request.queryMap()` for the first one will contain only 3 key-value pairs, and the second one will contain 4.

Comment: I'd agree with this reply. Also note that generally speaking, two vars of nesting would be the recommended maximum I'd use, three in extreme examples. For everything else, use query params.